# Android Read All notifications programmatically in status bar with root access

Tags: android, notifications, root

I know it is currently not possible to read messages via standart APIs. Is it possible to somehow read them with root access? Where are they stored? I have tried to locate the relevant places by browsing the source but no luck: [NotificationLogActivity.java](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/4.1.2_r1/com/android/notificationlog/NotificationLogActivity.java?av=f) and [NotificationManager](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android/android-core/platform-frameworks-base/android/app/NotificationManager.java.htm). I thought it might be in some SQLite db, but could not find any relevant system app database.

Where should I look into to find where the notifications are stored? I am currently cloning the Android source repo but not sure I will be able to find it.

Answer (score 0):

You simply can't do this. They are stored in memory only, inside the NotificationManagerService, StatusBarManagerService, and SystemUI.

Comment: But they still exist when the system is restarted?